# Should the [negative-energy] and [positive-energy] tags exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tags: [negative-energy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative-energy), [positive-energy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/positive-energy)

I'm really bothered by those two, they are only used in a few questions and usually either come together or only one of them is being used even if the question is asking about both.

I don't think they help those questions, but maybe a tag [energy-types] would.

Not only that, but we have a [channel-energy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel-energy) tag to make things more ambiguous (undead, healing, channel energy, positive energy, negative energy, undead, cleric).

Comment: I think the key is whether they represent a category of thing people can be experts on. I don't know the answer to that, or I'd leave an answer myself.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**

Because users have found them useful and have used them.

They are no worse or more picky than the hundred weird picky little D&D tags.

Tagging on RPG.SE is an emergent folksonomy, and we do not interfere with it unless there’s an actual problem.